# Programmatically stop mouseHold event

Tags: html, reactjs

In React I have a resizable column, which sort of breaks if the user clicks on the resizer, holds, and then moves the mouse outside of the browser window.

I run some code to re-enable pointer-events for some elements onMouseLeave, but the issue is that the Resizer still thinks that the user's mouse is being held when the cursor returns (even if they stopped holding outside of the browser window)

Is there a way to tell the HTML elements that the mouse is not being held down onMouseLeave, or maybe just cycle the click?